# What font is used for Swire's logo?

Tags: font-identification, logo, serif

[image: Swire logo]

This is an image of the [Swire](http://www.swire.com/en/index.php) logo font. I have been asked about this font for use and am trying to find it.  I thought I had the font but have since changed machines and can no longer locate it.

A vector version with additional glyphs is available in [this PDF](http://www.swire.com/en/sustainability/sd_reports/swire_ar2013.pdf).

[image: Swire Pacific logo]

What The Font didn't help, curious if anyone knows the font.

Comment: The font is very similar to: Friz Quadrata from Adobe Friz Quadrata. Maybe the font was edited to give the logo a unique look.

Comment: The font is very similar to: League of Legends from League of Legends. Maybe the font was edited to give the logo a unique look. –

Comment: Here you can look up the font using your image. http://www.whatfontis.com

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to use Friz Quadrata, which actually looks like the League of Legends font is based off as well.

Answer (score 5):

That particular font is a custom font for Swire called "Swire Roman".

I had a feeling that the font was customized; those rounded bottoms of the "W" are typical of how fonts are customized for brand logos.

I did a [search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3aswire.com+filetype%3apdf) on Swire's site for PDFs, thinking maybe I'd get lucky and find brand guidelines. Haven't yet, but I did find [this newsletter](http://swirenews.swire.com/uploads/files/term/2014third%2829Dec%29_compressed.pdf), which, when opened in Illustrator or Acrobat, revealed itself to be Swire Roman.

While this is the correct answer, I bet someone else can come up with a more helpful answer for you. I'm guessing that this is derived from something else that is close enough for you to use if you're trying to look like Swire but not *be* Swire. I did notice that [Swire has worked with Pentagram](http://swireproperties.us/swire-properties-unveils-branding-and-logo-for-brickell-city-centre/); perhaps Pentagram did the rebrand (which probably happened [after 2004](http://www.brandsoftheworld.com/logo/swire-group) and [before 2011](http://www.swire.com/en/sustainability/sd_reports/cpcs_2011.pdf))? If you can find some PR about the rebrand you might be able to get more info about the font's process - not a bad rabbit hole to chase if someone else can't match a similar font.

Also worth noting that they use Optima as a secondary font a lot, and while individual glyphs don't really match up, the overall 'feel' of Optima and Swire Roman aren't all that far off. See this example from [a PowerPoint](http://www.swire.com/en/sustainability/12goldenrules.pdf):

[image: Swire Oilfield Services, Reliably Dynamic]

Optima is below and it fits pretty well with the feel of the logo text.